# Normalise the JSON where Array as an value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I was trying to normalize a very deeply nested JSON which contains all possible ways JSON can be created. A part of JSON can be seen in below code snippet.

**What is my end goal**

I am converting the nested JSON into a simple JS object like below

```
{
  key1: value,
  key2: value,
  ...
}
```

Problem i faced with the below solution is that when it comes to `Objects with values as array`
i failed to find a way to see its key values.

if you run below code
key4,key5, key6 wont get displayed with the console.log only its value gets printed.

```
key1 -- values
key2 -- values
key3 -- value3
0 -- 
0 -- some_value
```

**Code snippet**

```js
const req = {
      request: {
        results: {
          key1: 'values',
          results: [
            {
              key2: 'values',
            },
          ],
        },
        params: {
          key3: 'value3',
          query: {
            key4: [''],
            key5: ['123456'],
            key6: ['some_value'],
          },
        },
      },
    };
    
function normaliseJSON(obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
      normaliseJSON(obj[k]);
    } else {
      console.log(`${k} -- ${obj[k]}`);
    }
  }
}

normaliseJSON(req);
```

Is there any way to get the keys of key4,5,6 ?
also open to any other solution to normalise such JSON

Comment: In the else block you can use     if(Array.isArray(obj[k])){ console.log(`${k} -- ${obj[k].toString()}`); }    This will print the array

Comment: The issue is that an array is technically an instance of an object. When you say you would like to normalize it, are you referring to getting all the leaf nodes except for arrays?

Comment: also key5 is repeated

Comment: @SrikantSahu i dont understand, can you explain it.

Comment: @NicholasFicara , I want everything in the new object including the Array's

Comment: If you want to have a simple key-pair, first be careful __your keys may collide__; second, your keys 4,5,6 being an array, needs special access to get their values. In this case, consider them having hidden indexes - 0,1,2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason your recursion goes inside the array is since `['123456'] instanceof Object` is `true` in javascript (`typeof(['asd'])` also gives `"object"`). To check if something is an array have to check with `Array.isArray(something)`
2. In template literals when you try to embed an array eg `...${['123456']}` in the end it will show as `...123456` without the brackets. Therefore in situation of Arrays need to `JSON.stringify(arr)`

There may be better ways of doing this but I created a function called `arrayHasObject` which checks if an array has object elements. This was to catch the inner `results` array and ignore `key4`,`key5` and `key6`.
The recursion will happen if `obj[k]` is an object and not an array or if `obj[k]` is an array and it has an object element.

Since recursion is hard to visualize I recommend https://pythontutor.com/  . It is mostly for Python but works for JS as well. It can help you visualize these things and to find where things go wrong

Ofcourse the way I have written it will break if something like `key4: [{a:'abc'}]` since `arrayHasObject` gives `true` for this. Maybe will need to change the function accordingly.

```js
function arrayHasObject(arr) {
    return arr.some((x) => typeof(x)==='object' && !Array.isArray(x))
}


const req = {
      request: {
        results: {
          key1: 'values',
          results: [
            {
              key2: 'values',
            },
          ],
        },
        params: {
          key3: 'value3',
          query: {
            key4: [''],
            key5: ['123456'],
            key6: ['some_value'],
          },
        },
      },
    };
    
    
function normaliseJSON(obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if ((obj[k] instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(obj[k])) || (Array.isArray(obj[k]) && arrayHasObject(obj[k]))) {
      normaliseJSON(obj[k]);
    } else {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[k])){
       console.log(`${k} -- ${JSON.stringify(obj[k])}`);
      }
      else{
       console.log(`${k} -- ${obj[k]}`);
      }
     
    }
  }
}

normaliseJSON(req);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot